# Kotlin flow: initialize MutableStateFlow with value from another Flow

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewmodel, kotlin-flow

Hi I have the following situation:

```
private val _flow = myRepo.list.map{//do stuff}
private val _mutableFlow = MutableStateFlow(listOf<Any>())
```

I want `_mutableFlow` to be initialized with values from `_flow`, and it needs to be mutable so I can later emit values to it. of course using `map()` wouldn't work as it returns a `Flow`. It doesn't need to be reactive to changes from `_flow`, it's just a one-time thing

Is there any way (even an hacky one) to achieve this?

Comment: Seems like you should rethink your design. What is your actual use case? And why won't you use values from your immutable flow straight ahead instead of emitting them to another flow?

Comment: What do you want to happen when you start emitting items to the flow, but `_flow` is also still emitting items? Is `_flow` a finite flow, and if so, do you want to forbid emitting the extra stuff directly until after `_flow` is complete?

Comment: changing design is not an option unfortunately as the myRepo.list is code used elsewhere. I can assume _flow is only emitted once, however it may not be emitted yet at the moment _mutableFlow is initialized, otherwise I could simply do _flow.value.
_flow will basically contain an initial configuration that the user can then modify, however in a particular case, that user's configuration is empty and they decide to remove the initial one, i cannot emit on _flow (_mutable would be emtpy again and will not fire) and thus other flows downstream that rely on boht _flow and _mutable will not change